# Re-coding a Variable using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have ICD 9 codes for Pulmonary embolism in my dataset starting from column DX1 to DX25 and I want to create a separate column for Pulmonary Embolism (PE) in my dataset (xs) with the ICD 9 codes. So if the ICD 9 code is present anywhere from DX1 to DX25 I want to code that as 1 else 0.  I also don't want to use a for loop because my dataset has 30,000 rows and the dataset is 7GB so It crashes my computer.
At present I am doing this with the following code :

```
xs$PE = NA

xs[which(xs$DX1%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX2%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX3%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1      
xs[which(xs$DX4%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX5%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1           
xs[which(xs$DX6%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX7%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1           
xs[which(xs$DX8%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1           
xs[which(xs$DX9%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1           
xs[which(xs$DX10%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX11%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX12%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX13%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX14%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX15%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX16%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX17%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1          
xs[which(xs$DX18%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1     
xs[which(xs$DX19%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX20%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1
xs[which(xs$DX21%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1  
xs[which(xs$DX22%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1          
xs[which(xs$DX23%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1          
xs[which(xs$DX24%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1          
xs[which(xs$DX25%in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")), "PE"] <- 1  

xs <- xs %>%
      mutate(PE = ifelse(is.na(PE),0,PE))
```

can anyone Help me with a smarter way to recode this using dplyr?[I don't want to type 100 lines of code because I have other diagnoses that I want to code and create new columns]

Comment: Honestly, for a dataset of your size you might find `data.table` a better choice since I believe it is geared towards very large datasets. What is the original format of the data? CSV? SQL database?

Comment: The data set is in SPSS format and I used library(haven) to read the data set. I have no problem reading data set, but I want to code the ICD9codes in a smarter way using dplyr.

Comment: xs$PEN <- 1 * (rowSums(xs[paste0('DX', 1:25)] %in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519")) > 0)
Error in base::rowSums(x, na.rm = na.rm, dims = dims, ...) : 
  'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions

Comment: That one is wrong so I deleted it. Try this one: `y <- xs[paste0('DX', 1:25)];
y[] <- as.matrix(y) %in% c("41511", "41512", "41513", "41519");
xs$PE <- 1 * (rowSums(y) > 0)`. Or you can share your sample data with us like the results of `head(dput(xs))`

Comment: in your code, the `which` is redundant

Comment: But what if I have multiple diagoses to code, for example I have to create a new column for VTE (Venous Thrombo embolism) and the ICD 9 codes are "4532", "4533", "45340", "45341", "45342", "45382", "45383", "45384", "45385", "45386", "45387", "45388", "45389", "4539", "4530", "452", "325", "41511", "41512", "41513", "41519", "45111", "45119", "4512", "45181", "45183", "45184","45189". So I have to use your code separtely for creating this? Or is there any way you can merge these values in your code?

Comment: @mt1022 Your code worked. Thanks, But what if I have multiple diagoses to code, for example I have to create a new column for VTE (Venous Thrombo embolism) and the ICD 9 codes are "4532", "4533", "45340", "45341", "45342", "45382", "45383", "45384", "45385", "45386", "45387", "45388", "45389", "4539", "4530", "452", "325", "41511", "41512", "41513", "41519", "45111", "45119", "4512", "45181", "45183", "45184","45189". So I have to use your code separtely for creating this? Or is there any way you can merge these values in your code?

Comment: I think you can make a list of all the doagoses and do it in a for-loop.

Comment: @mt1022 for loop is crashing my memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've done similar work in the past I've used a combination of tidyr and dplyr.

My first step is to reshape long, then look for the diagnosis. 
The data set can then be reduced to a single row per id. 
If required, this can be merged back to the original data set. 
However, I haven't tried this with a data set as large as yours.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), 
                  diagnosis1 = c("001", "001", "005"), 
                  diagnosis2 = c("002", "002", "002"), 
                  diagnosis3 = c("003", "005", "004"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dat
  id diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3
1  1        001        002        003
2  2        001        002        005
3  3        005        002        004

# reshape long
long_dat <- gather(dat, key = diagnosis_code, value = string, -id)
head(long_dat)
  id diagnosis_code string
1  1     diagnosis1    001
2  2     diagnosis1    001
3  3     diagnosis1    005
4  1     diagnosis2    002
5  2     diagnosis2    002
6  3     diagnosis2    002

long_dat <- long_dat %>% 
  mutate(has_001 = ifelse(string == "001", 1, 0),
         has_4_or_5 = ifelse(string %in% c("004", "005"), 1, 0)
         )

# reduce to single line per id
long_dat <- long_dat %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise(has_001 = max(has_001), 
            has_4_or_5 = max(has_4_or_5))
long_dat
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id has_001 has_4_or_5
  <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1       1          0
2     2       1          1
3     3       0          1

dat <- left_join(dat, long_dat)
dat
  id diagnosis1 diagnosis2 diagnosis3 has_001 has_4_or_5
1  1        001        002        003       1          0
2  2        001        002        005       1          1
3  3        005        002        004       0          1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I coded.

Creating new columns for different diseases from ICD 9 codes [DX1 to DX25] for 1 : DTV [ Deep Vein Thrombosis].

```
y <- xs[paste0('DX', 1:25)] 
y[] <- as.matrix(y) %in% c("4532", "4533", "45340", "45341", "45342", "45382", "45383", "45384", "45385", "45386", "45387", "45388", "45389", "4539") 
xs$DTV <- 1 * (rowSums(y) > 0)
```